# navigate to a specific page number of pdf document

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I am developing a pdf reader, it reads large pdf files now I want to develop a system by which I can navigate among the pages of the documents. Can you suggest me some way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CGPDFDocument and its associated classes. They're designed for this sort of stuff.